# Button html triggering active keyboard on IOS?

Tags: html, ios, css

We have built a site with a login page - login page is a simple form in field sets - annoyingly when using an iPad the keyboard is triggered whenever pressing the button - it stays active as the next page is loaded - i can understand why - following is the form code - is there any way to disable this functionality?

```
<section>
<h3>Login</h3>



<form method="post" action="/Login" novalidate="novalidate" _lpchecked="1">    <fieldset>
    <label class="ui-front legend icon-img-inside">
        <label for="FormModel_UserName">User Name</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="FormModel.UserName" id="FormModel_UserName" data-val-required="Please provide your User Name" data-val="true" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="FormModel_UserName-error" class="input-validation-error" aria-invalid="true">
        <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="FormModel.UserName" class="field-validation-error"><span id="FormModel_UserName-error" class="">Please provide your User Name</span></span>
        <img alt="Icon: Person" src="/css/img/icons/icon-user.svg">
    </label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <label class="ui-front legend icon-img-inside">
        <label for="FormModel_Password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="FormModel.Password" id="FormModel_Password" data-val-required="Please provide your Password" data-val="true" aria-required="true" class="input-validation-error" aria-describedby="FormModel_Password-error">
        <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="FormModel.Password" class="field-validation-error"><span id="FormModel_Password-error" class="">Please provide your Password</span></span>
        <img alt="Icon: Pencil" src="/css/img/icons/icon-pencil.svg">
    </label>
</fieldset>
<div data-valmsg-summary="true" class="validation-summary-errors"><ul>   <li>Please provide your User Name</li><li>Please provide your Password</li>   </ul></div>    <fieldset>
    <button class="button" name="submit" type="submit">
        <i class="key"></i>
        <span>Login</span>
    </button>
</fieldset>
```

```
<!-- Javascript detection -->
<span class="result-login" id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to disable native, default submit process and do submiting with js,, something like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0].onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    document.getElementById('frm1').submit();
}
```

see the code here, I changed some tag names, look the html pane also..: http://codepen.io/mkdizajn/pen/EgmPQR?editors=1010

I can't see this live and test but I hope that helps..